# Django Admin - show json value as in tabular format

Tags: python, django, json, django-models, django-admin

Example:

I have a model with columns as id and data, its populated as below

```
1 | {name: 'Foo', age: 65, grade : 'A'}
2 | {name: 'Bar', age: 56, grade: 'A+'}
```

now in admin(not in list display) I want to see the data column as in Tabular Format some thing like below

```
name : Foo
age  : 65
grade: A
```

and when I edit the fields it has to store again as json string in DB

is it possible ?

please provide me referenc.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it's a non-sense to use json as storage for this.

Comment: Hey thanks , its an example, real scenario is different. could you please let me know where can I find the reference for this

Comment: All you need to know is here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ .

Comment: finding in that total documentation is difficult , I am newbie to django,please give me a reference to similar example.

Comment: There's no reference to a similar example and no "copy-paste" solution so you'll have to read the doc (to get a better knowledge and understanding of what Django provides), read at least part of the source code (to understand how features you will have to build upon are actually implemented) and then write some code. That's how we all learn.